# P-value of 1 and parametric bootstrap for random effects in glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmmtmb

I am running mixed models in glmmTMB, and I'm using likelihood ratio tests to test the significance of my random effects. Mostly this is working fine, but in some cases the LRT gives me a p-value of 1 for the random effect. Can a p-value of 1 be valid in cases like this?

I've seen it said that when an LRT gives a p-value of 1, it should be checked with a parametric bootstrap. Is this necessary? If so, how do I go about using parametric bootstraps for my random effects in glmmTMB?

For example, one of my models is `Model14 <- glmmTMB(Nodules ~ Species + N.Level + Species:N.Level + (1|Block) + (1|Acc), family=nbinom1, data=D25NLNTL)`

I use likelihood ratio tests to test the significance of each predictor (removing the predictor of interest, and running an anova on this and the full model). For all of my terms I get reasonable p-values, but for my block random effect I get

```
Data: D25NLNTL
Models:
LNTLnodsModel14nullC: Nodules ~ Species + N.Level + Species:N.Level + (1 | Acc), zi=~0, disp=~1
LNTLnodsModel14: Nodules ~ Species + N.Level + Species:N.Level + (1 | Block) + , zi=~0, disp=~1
LNTLnodsModel14:     (1 | Acc), zi=~0, disp=~1
                     Df    AIC    BIC logLik deviance Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
LNTLnodsModel14nullC  6 841.41 859.43 -414.7   829.41                        
LNTLnodsModel14       7 843.41 864.43 -414.7   829.41     0      1          1
```

Comment: Could you add an example in which this issue occurs.

Comment: Edited to add an example.

Comment: this very likely means that your random-effects variance was estimated as zero, so removing the term/parameter from the model makes no difference to the log-likelihood: this will give a p-value of 1 and an AIC difference of 2, as observed.

Comment: Are reviewers unlikely to take issue with p-values like this being reported, then?